# CMake include OpenCV on ArchLinux

Tags: c++, opencv, clion

When I want to compile my project in Clion 5, I get the following error message:

```
undefined reference to `cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::Rect_<int>, std::allocator<cv::Rect_<int> > >&, double, int, int, cv::Size_<int>, cv::Size_<int>)'
```

My problem is that there is no entry for opencv as found sometimes on stackoverlow.com

[cmake cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srdtw.png)

Can anybody tell me, how to include the OpenCV library?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code is a call to detectMultiScale from the opencv lib and it is wrong linked. In fact you didn't include anything. Edit you CMakeLists file like this:

```
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

add_executable(you_binary_name)

target_link_libraries(you_binary_name ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/mylib.so)
```